# Diferenças entre TensorFlow e DialogFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Então, estou iniciando no mundo da IA e Machine Learning e digamos que nem tudo é bem explicado para iniciantes (talvez má vontade minha? talvez). Eu queria que alguém me explicasse a diferença entre TensorFlow e DialogFlow, e caso abordem a mesma coisa, qual a vantagem de cada um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confesso que não conhecia o Dialogflow até então, por isso posso não ter uma resposta 100% completa.

Mas até aonde entendi o Dialogflow é uma plataforma que auxilia no desenvolvimento de aplicações que necessitam de NLU (Natural Language Understanding). Digamos que você queira criar um app no qual o usuário fala com o celular qual item do menu ele quer acessar, nesse caso o DialogFlow se aplica bem. Ele funciona como uma abstração dos métodos de IA, sendo útil quando quer desenvolver algo de forma rápida e/ou na qual a IA não é o diferencial.

Já TensorFlow é uma biblioteca focada em redes neurais, que hoje estão na maior parte dos algoritmos de Aprendizado de Máquina. Você poderia implementar tudo que o DialogFlow te oferece pelo TensorFlow, mas teria que fazer mais na "mão".

Se seu objetivo é estudar e aprender IA, estudar Tensorflow é uma excelente forma. Se você for muito iniciante eu recomendo começar pelo SciKit Learn, que tem as técnicas mais básicas de Aprendizado de Máquina, mas vão te permitir ter vivência no meio.